# If I install Ubuntu linux on an external hard drive can I save the data on that same hard drive?

Tags: installation, hard-drive, external-hdd

I am planning on installing Ubuntu on an external hard drive.  My question is where does data get saved when I use this OS?  For instance, if I create a folder on the desktop of Ubuntu where is that information being saved?  Ideally, I want all data related to my Ubuntu OS stored on the external drive… Is this possible?

Comment: Perhaps you're interested in this question: 

* http://askubuntu.com/questions/16988/how-do-i-install-ubuntu-to-a-usb-key-without-using-startup-disk-creator

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to install Ubuntu on portable external Hard Drive?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/446682/how-to-install-ubuntu-on-portable-external-hard-drive)

Answer (score 2):

It will be saved on whatever partition you install it on. As long as you can boot from the hard disk, it will save there.